# What does it mean that the Son did not know the hour of his return in Matthew 24:36 // Mark 13:32?

Tags: matthew, mark, christology, olivet-discourse, second-coming

I'm little lost here. Can somebody please help me with this? We have these two verses concerning the day when (as introduced in Mark 13:26 // Mark 24:30) the Son of Man returns in glory:

> But of that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels of heaven, nor the Son, but the Father alone.
>   **(Matthew 24:36 - NASB)**

> But of that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but the Father alone.
>   **(Mark 13:32 - NASB)**

I know the normal interpretations of this verses, but I recently watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfdozI26lQQ) from “Inspiring Philosophy” that has a different explanation from what I’ve heard.

The video claims that in these verses Jesus was alluding to ancient marriage customs. As they describe it, the groom’s father had the ultimate authority to decide when the couple would marry, but the bride, groom, and entire community were aware of the plan due to the necessity of extensive wedding planning within the community. In the same way, they claim that Jesus was not making a statement about actually *not knowing* the day and hour but was instead deferring to the Father’s authority to determine the hour.

It sounds interesting, but when I check my commentaries, I can't find any interpreting it that way. Why is that? Is this a legitimate interpretation?

Comment: Hi Edgear, I thought this would be more likely to generate a useful Q&A if people didn’t have to watch the video to figure out what it was about. (It is, it must be said, a concise and clear explanation of their viewpoint for anyone interested in watching it.) I expanded the question by summarizing the video, but feel free to adjust however you see fit if I’ve misunderstood any aspect of what you’re asking.

Comment: No comment on video. The interpretation of statement about limitation of Jesus knowledge is commonly discussed in reference to **Kenotic Theology** which is an exploration of the christological implications of the Incarnation in reference to: Christ "emptied Himself" (Philippians 2:7). This is pretty heavy sledding for a bible study forum.

Comment: I've studied this before and will try to link some resources and hopefully give an answer later. However, understanding the marriage custom in whole is imperative to understanding the church as the bride of Christ. Everything from his coming, giving himself, leaving, giving a token of his return in the Holy Spirit, our duty to remain ready and his eventual second coming are all there in vivid detail.

Comment: My two cents - There is a difference between the Second Coming and The visitations called The Days of the Lord. Brmicke.com

Answer (score 9):

The video referenced by the question does a decent job of presenting the basics of the Jewish wedding customs and how it relates to Matthew 24:36 and Mark 13:32. However, I feel it lacks background, detail and also skips an important relevant piece.

### Groundwork

I'll give a quick summary of the wedding custom as I have researched.
The basic order of the [entire process:](http://messianicfellowship.50webs.com/wedding.html)

1. Shiddukhin - The Selection of the bride. In ancient times it was customary for the father of the groom to find a bride for his son and make the arrangements.[Genesis 24:1-32](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=24&t=ESV)
2. Ketubah - The marriage contract is negotiated and agreed upon. [Genesis 24:33-52](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=24&t=ESV)
3. Mohar - The bridal payment. It is given to the bride's family, but really belongs to the bride. [Genesis 24:53](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=24&t=ESV), [29:20,27](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=29&t=ESV), [1 Corinthians 7:23](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=1Co&c=7&t=ESV), [1 Peter 18-19](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=1Pe&c=1&t=ESV)
4. Eyrusin/Kiddushin/Betrothal - The Groom prepares to leave. For the next (roughly) year they are betrothed but live apart. The groom prepares a wedding chamber.
5. Matan - Pledge. When the groom leaves he gives the bride a gift, a pledge of his return. [2 Cor 1:21-22](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=2Co&c=1&t=ESV)
6. Nissuin - Marriage. When the groom's father approves it is ready, the groom may go collect his bride. His return is joyful with fanfare and trumpets. There is a 7 day feast and the couple go off to the room that was prepared (again, usually at his father's house). Details of private ceremony preceding the wedding chamber with large public feast afterward can vary.

### The Question

The video and these two passages connect at the 4th step: The Betrothal period.

What the video got right:

- The community and the bride generally knew the year and the month, but the day and the hour were unknown.
- Saying "only my Father knows" does not mean Jesus is ignorant, but rather submissive and respectful to his Father's authority.

What the video left out or didn't highlight:

- The "only my Father knows" line is not just a common phrase, it is a scripted response for all questions about the wedding, even a ceremonial response:

  > When a Jewish lad would propose marriage to a prospective bride, he would offer her a cup of wine. If she drank it, she was accepting the betrothal. He would then inform her that he was to go to his father's house to prepare a place for her. She would typically respond, "When are you coming back?" The prospective groom would reply by saying, "Only my father knows!" <sup>[Norten](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/unlocking-the-secrets-of-the-feasts-michael-norten/1111902791?ean=9781449734107)</sup>
- This marriage script is also quoted by Jesus elsewhere. John 14:2-3 (ESV) says:

  > 2 In my Father’s house are many rooms. If it were not so, would I have told you that I go to prepare a place for you?
  >   3 And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come again and will take you to myself, that where I am you may be also.

Jesus was not even the first to connect the Christ to the bridegroom and his chosen people as the bride. John the Baptist, while correcting the idea that he was the Christ, says that he who has the bride is the bridegroom and suggests that he is one of the bridegroom's two friends (part of the final wedding ceremony) [John 3:29](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jhn&c=3&t=ESV).

Jewish theology understood the illustration of marriage as applying to God's *Ketubah* with his people at Mt. Sinai. [*Note: I can find many mentions, but a comprehensive reference eludes me. Any help would be appreciated*]

### Objections

Just because other illustrations are used by Jesus does not mean that the allegory of Jewish marriage is faulty or cannot be trusted, it simply means it is not a complete picture. It is the picture of his relationship with his bride, the bride's responsibility in the meantime to remain vigilant (that Matthew 25 and the waiting brides is the next passage is no coincidence), and his promise to return and take his bride to live with him forever. It's not meant to speak of his relationship to those who are not his bride, or to what happens to those who don't make it into the feast. Other illustrations may, but not this one.

And just because the Jewish marriage process is not completely scriptural (though we can see it in action in scripture) does not mean that truth cannot be communicate using it. Those listening to Jesus tell the parables could easily have said the same of the parables at the time. They could have discounted or ignored them because they were not in the Torah, but Jesus had important truths to share through them. Truths that do exist in some form or principle in the Old Testament.

Unfortunately, the basic knowledge needed to understand this obvious illustration was lost as the church became more influenced by Greek and then Roman thought and its Jewish roots and founders were intermingled and watered down. Italian bishops, let alone common people, would have had no reference to the Jewish wedding customs. Countless theologians throughout history have struggled with these verses when they make no connection to Jewish thought. Harlod F. Carl write an article, [Only the Father Knows](http://www.mountainretreatorg.net/articles/only_the_father_knows.shtml), which summarizes interpretation throughout church history and then seeks to arrive at the best solution. There is not a single mention in Carl's own work or in the work of these major theologians of the Jewish Wedding customs! One might take this as reason to dismiss it, but the direct quotes and context provided by scripture are undeniable. We can be thankful we live in a time when such information can be shared by our Jewish brothers and sisters easily so that we might better understand scripture.

## Conclusion

If we try to understand Jesus' words the way the Jews would have heard them, we cannot deny that Jesus was explicitly quoting and calling up the imagery of marriage.
Within this illustration, Jesus is not saying he does not know the day or hour (as a groom may very well have known from conversations with his father), but is really giving preference to his Father's authority.
First of all, Jesus is always submissive to the Father, and secondly it gave Jesus the opportunity to intentionally reference marriage custom to his listeners.
They understood immediately everything that went along with the context of the betrothal. The listeners, even the Disciples, may not have understood its implications for the groom, Jesus, immediately, but we can be confident that they got the picture after he returned to his Father's home.
After all, the marriage imagery of the church as the bride is a continuing illustration in Paul and John's writings.

---

Other sources not directly cited:
http://ldolphin.org/risk/ult.shtml
http://www.wildolive.co.uk/weddings.htm
http://www.gotquestions.org/Jewish-wedding-traditions.html
http://www.laydownlife.net/yedidah/AncientJewishWeddingCeremony.htm
http://www.betemunah.org/wedding.html

Comment: I didn't get into how the illustration of the wedding then applies  to eschatology as it seemed to me the basic question was "*Is this what Jesus was saying*" not "*if  is what Jesus meant how does it effect eschatology?*" If the original questioner did want implications, let me know and I can attempt to add that. I think that one proof that this is truth is that the other details, the bride waiting for the groom's return for example, can still be found and understood in scripture. Recognizing the wedding illustration enhances our understanding but is not exclusive to understanding.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only resolution to the implication of non-omniscience i've found satisfactory. The current commentaries assume Jesus was referring to His human nature here but there is no indication anywhere else that He was less than omniscient. Probably will answer a lot of objections to the Trinity on StackExchange.

Comment: Best answer. God explanations

Answer (score 3):

I viewed the video. It's a good parallel, but it do not line up with scriptures as to his omniscience in this question. To understand the answer that I'm about to give, one must first understand God as the Diversity, or the share of himself in flesh and bones. The Son is God in flesh, glorified, and is in all/full power, he should know as God the father knows.

The answer as to why he do not know his return date lay in the biblical principle of the "will". Supportive scripture: Matthew 6:3:

> But when thou doest alms, let not thy left hand know what thy right hand doeth.

How can one do something themselves without knowing about it? Your right hand, is a part of you, as your left hand is a part of you. You know exactly what each hand is doing. The answer is an act of one's “WILL”. Lets see how God does it. Jeremiah 31:34:

> And they shall teach no more every man his neighbour, and every man his brother, saying, Know the LORD: for they shall all know me, from the least of them unto the greatest of them, saith the LORD: for I will forgive their iniquity, and I will remember their sin no more

And I (will) remember their sin no more? How can an aAlmighty, all knowing God not remember?  Is he, the Father, not omniscient? So how can He (God the Father) "NOT REMEMBER?". The answer is that it's an act of the will. Supportive scripture: Revelation chapter 5. In this passage, our Lord Jesus is sitting on the throne. What happens?, the Spirit, (the Father, the LAMB, and not the Lamb of God), comes and takes the book out of His (the Son) hand. Question, which hand did he take the book out of? Answer the right hand, remember, Matthew 6:3:

> But when thou doest alms, let not thy left hand know what thy right hand doeth.

So by taking the book out of this "RIGHT" hand He (the Son, God, shared in flesh) now wills not to KNOW his return DATE. For that date is sealed in the scrolls, now taken out of his hands.  The symbolism for us to understand is this: the book/scroll that WAS in his right hand contain all the information of what's the future holds, including the return date of the Son.  So only the Father (the Spirit) knows that date. Our Lord being in flesh and bone, as High priest, is a sitting priest, which indicates his work is finished on earth. He now fulfills the DAVIDIC PROPHECY of Psalms 110:1:

> The LORD said unto my Lord, Sit thou at my right hand, until I make thine enemies thy footstool.

The "until" date is written in the book that was in our Lord's right hand. No one knows, only he who took the book. Again the beauty of the “diversity” of God in flesh and bones.

Conclusion: as the equal share of himself sitting on the throne as High Priest, He willed not to know the date, by the removal of the book from his own hands. This is symbolically for us to understand his will not to know.

Answer (score 3):

The return of the Messiah was to be the day of judgment upon reprobate Jerusalem:

> Luk 19:41-44 KJV - 41 And when he was come near [IE: to Jerusalem], he beheld the city, and wept over it, 42 Saying, If thou hadst known, even thou, at least in this thy day, the things which belong unto thy peace! but now they are hid from thine eyes. 43 For the days shall come upon thee, that thine enemies shall cast a trench about thee, and compass thee round, and keep thee in on every side, 44 And shall lay thee even with the ground, and thy children within thee; and they shall not leave in thee one stone upon another; **because thou knewest not the time of thy visitation**.

Job had complained that God does not publish a schedule of court dates when the righteous can bring their complaint before the Judge:

> Job 24:1 NIV - 1 "Why does the Almighty not set times for judgment? Why must those who know him look in vain for such days?

So, Jesus says that his coming to judge the righteous and the unrighteous would be by secret timing:

> Luk 12:40, 46 KJV - 40 Be ye therefore ready also: for the Son of man cometh at an hour when ye think not. ... 46 The lord of that servant will come in a day when he looketh not for him, and at an hour when he is not aware, and will cut him in sunder, and will appoint him his portion with the unbelievers.

As does Paul:

> 1Th 5:1-3 KJV - 1 But of the times and the seasons, brethren, ye have no need that I write unto you. 2 For yourselves know perfectly that the day of the Lord so cometh as a thief in the night. 3 For when they shall say, Peace and safety; then sudden destruction cometh upon them, as travail upon a woman with child; and they shall not escape.

Jesus not only did not know the day or the hour, he also did not know which season of the year it was to occur:

> Mat 24:20 KJV - 20 But pray ye that your flight be not in the winter, neither on the sabbath day:

He didn't know during which watch of the day he was coming:

> Mat 24:42-44 KJV - 42 Watch therefore: for ye know not what hour your Lord doth come. 43 But know this, that if the goodman of the house had known in what watch the thief would come, he would have watched, and would not have suffered his house to be broken up. 44 Therefore be ye also ready: for in such an hour as ye think not the Son of man cometh.

The only thing he knew was that it was to occur while some of his associates were alive:

> Mat 24:34 KJV - 34 Verily I say unto you, This generation shall not pass, till all these things be fulfilled.
>   Mar 13:30 KJV - 30 Verily I say unto you, that this generation shall not pass, till all these things be done.
>   Luk 21:32 KJV - 32 Verily I say unto you, This generation shall not pass away, till all be fulfilled.

Jesus was not, nor is, all-knowing. He denies that idea explicitly and says that his knowledge is limited to that which God reveals to him:

> Jhn 15:15 NIV - 15 I no longer call you servants, because a servant does not know his master's business. Instead, I have called you friends, for everything that I learned from my Father I have made known to you.

Had he known the timing he would have told his friends.

However, God did give him a revelation of that great day (70ad) when Jerusalem was judged and the temple destroyed:

> Rev 1:1 NIV - 1 The revelation from Jesus Christ, **which God gave him** to show his servants what must soon take place. He made it known by sending his angel to his servant John,

So to answer the question, Jesus was confessing that he did not know the date and the hour (nor the season or watch of the night) because God had not yet revealed it to him. He only knew what God had revealed to him. When God gave him more details he signified them by his servant John.

Claiming that Jesus is "omniscient" is simply pious ignorance.

Comment: A fine answer, I fully agree with you.+1

Comment: Relevant passage: [Act 17:31 CSB] (31) "because he [God] **has set a day when he is going to judge** the world in righteousness by the man he has appointed. He has provided proof of this to everyone by raising him from the dead."

Comment: When one has clear ideas.... +1

Answer (score 2):

The video explaining the custom of a Jewish wedding helps to understand why Jesus (as the Son) lacks this information. Here are reasons why I would not settle for this as an explanation:

- The customs of the Jewish marriage ceremony are a part of the imagery used to bring understanding to Biblical principles, but they are **customs** not truth. The proper role of such extra-Biblical elements is to illustrate, not define principles. When the custom is a correct picture, it is because it points to truth found in the Bible.
- Jesus used examples which do not fit the marriage ceremony to illustrate His return. He spoke of a Master returning to His servants; a landowner returning to His estate.
- When Jesus comes again He will accomplish things which are not part of the marriage ceremony. He will judge the living and the dead. He will engage in a final battle to defeat Satan and all followers of evil.

When Jesus says:

> *“But of that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels of heaven, but My Father only…  (Matthew 24:36 NKJV)*

The proper way to understand what He means is to examine that statement within the context of Biblical truth which customs (such as the marriage ceremony) help to illustrate (in part).

The primary element of Biblical time is linear: there is a sequence of unique events moving to a consummation of God’s purposes. There is a secondary cyclical element of time: people are to remember God’s work. On a weekly or annual cycle, God calls His people to remember what He has done in the past. In remembrance there is a present action to recall past works resulting in looking to the future consummation. In the example of the marriage ceremony each event is unique; at the same time there intervals between events. The intervals are filled with remembrances and look ahead to the future. This leads to another reason why the marriage ceremony is only an illustration: the consummation of the marriage is not the wedding ceremony.

While the events are for God’s purposes and not scheduled by the calendar, an omniscient God knows exactly when they will occur. This is the issue upon which the question rests. It also calls into question the nature of Jesus; for if He is truly God, He should know all things.

The Bible offers examples of God’s work and the calendar:

> *And he said to me, “For two thousand three hundred days; then the sanctuary shall be cleansed." (Daniel 8:14 NKJV)*
>
> *“Know therefore and understand,
> That from the going forth of the command
> To restore and build Jerusalem
> Until Messiah the Prince,
> There shall be seven weeks and sixty-two weeks;
> The street shall be built again, and the wall,
> Even in troublesome times." (Daniel 9:25 NKJV)*

The works described follow one another by a set amount of time between them. Using the principle of a day/year would lead to the conclusion that the number of years between events is significant.

With that in mind, compare what Jesus said in this question with another event which will take place around the time of His Coming:

> *“But of that **day and hour** no one knows, not even the angels of heaven, but My Father only…  (Matthew 24:36 NKJV)*
>
> *So the four angels, who had been prepared for the **hour and day and month and year**, were released to kill a third of mankind. (Revelation 9:15 NKJV)*

Only the **hour and day** are **not** known. There is nothing to support an understanding that Jesus has **no** knowledge of the timing of the event. Rather the conclusion is that Jesus knows the month and the year. This understanding is also consistent with other end time events:

> *Therefore rejoice, O heavens, and you who dwell in them! Woe to the inhabitants of the earth and the sea! For the devil has come down to you, having great wrath, because he knows that he has a short time.” (Revelation 12:12 NKJV)*

When Satan and his followers are cast from heaven to the earth he knows his time is short. Like Jesus, he knows the month and the year but lacks the exact hour and day.

Following the example of the marriage customs, the son has a general idea when the event will take place; what he lacks is the precise hour and day. This leads to another reason why the marriage ceremony is only an illustration not an explanation: the father may set the **day**, but the bride has the ability to determine the **hour**.

The answer to the question lies in finding the reason why Jesus would not know the hour and day while knowing the month and year.

Stating time to a precise hour requires a standard reference point. For example the Royal Observatory is used to set a world standard of Greenwich Mean Time or Universal Time. It is meaningless to point to a specific day and hour without first defining a specific location on the earth which serves as a reference point.

A second issue lies in measuring the length of a day. Someone on the surface of the earth using the sun will measure 4 minutes more than someone watching from heaven. In the natural world this is the difference between the solar and sidereal day. When Jesus, the LORD of the Sabbath, was physically present on the earth, how were His Sabbaths measured? By His earthly position or His heavenly throne? His public ministry lasted 3-4 years. The natural world makes it possible to measure the amount of time until His return by two equally valid means with a 3 ½ day difference between them. The natural world has been created such that a minor uncertainty in time is possible.

Another consideration is found in Numbers 6 which describes the vow of the Nazarite. When made by an individual for themselves it was for a fixed period of time. A person making this vow was forbidden to touch a dead body, to be in the house with a dead person, or to accompany a corpse to the grave. If the person inadvertently violated this prohibition, they had to undergo purification after which the time of their vow started over. The elements of the vow of the Nazarite are found in the details of the Last Supper. When Jesus made His vow, it would be interrupted by the events of His death. Regardless of what one believes happened during the 3-days and 3-nights before His resurrection, Jesus makes a statement which affirms His vow would be interrupted and have to start again:

> *Then one of the criminals who were hanged blasphemed Him, saying, “If You are the Christ, save Yourself and us.” But the other, answering, rebuked him, saying, “Do you not even fear God, seeing you are under the same condemnation? And we indeed justly, for we receive the due reward of our deeds; but this Man has done nothing wrong.” Then he said to Jesus, “Lord, remember me when You come into Your kingdom.” And Jesus said to him, “Assuredly, I say to you, today you will be with Me in Paradise.” (Luke 23:39-43 NKJV)*

The events on the cross ensured Jesus would have a Nazarite vow interrupted. After this He would need to undergo the purification process and then His time would start again. The exact period of time after His death until the vow could start again is the unknown factor. While it is unknown, it is only a matter of a few days which explains why only His Father in heaven knows the exact hour and day and Jesus and the rest of the angels know the month and year.

In summary, the physical incarnation of God in human form on the earth leads to an uncertainty on the precise measurement of time by God on the earth and God in heaven. This uncertainty is only possible if God is simultaneously on earth and in heaven.

That means the answer to statement Jesus makes is also saying He is God.

Answer (score 2):

**What does it mean that the Son did not know the hour of his return in Matthew 24:36 // Mark 13:32?**

**Signs of the End of the Age**

Matthew 24:3  (NASB)

> 3 As He was sitting on the Mount of Olives, the disciples came to Him
>   privately, saying, “Tell us, when will these things happen, and what
>   will be the sign of Your coming, and of the [a]end of the age?”

And in reply Jesus said to them.

Matthew 24:36 - (NASB)

> "But of that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels of heaven,
>   nor the Son, but the Father alone."

Basically  Jesus is telling us that the father knows more than the Son, if Jesus was part of an Almighty God,he would have known "that day or hour". Some may say that he did not know whilst in his human nature, however if the holy spirit was part of the same God as the Father, why then did Jesus did not say that it knows what the Father knows?

Answer (score 2):

> [Matthew 24:36] But of that day and hour knoweth no one, not even the angels of heaven, neither the Son, but the Father only.
>
> [Mark 13:32]But of that day or that hour knoweth no one, not even the angels in heaven, neither the Son, but the Father.

Both were answers to the questions of his disciples "Tell us, when shall these things be?" talking about the return of the Son of Man. There is another instance where they ask a similar question Act 1:7 but with Jesus glorified after the resurrection.

> [Acts 1:7] And he said unto them, **It is not for you to know times or seasons**, which the Father hath set within his own authority.

In here He points out that the purpose of the fig tree parable and the announcement of the comming of the Lord is for the disciples to be prepared at any moment and shared the gospel. In this answer Jesus does not tell them that Him not know the day, but that **we** (people) can not know the day. This passage shed light and clarify that is not that Jesus did not know the moment of the second comming, but is about His submission to the Father authority. We can interpret the first two verses like this: *But of that day and hour only the Father has the right to say when will it be*

Answer (score 2):

**What was Jesus referring to when he said, No man knows the day or time/hr of his return?**

To say that Jesus didn't know would suggest he is not all knowing. So, he must have said it in the context of affirming his humanity on earth -- he didn't know as he was fully man when he came to save man from their sins. But he also said he and the Father are One, which makes him one with God in divinity.

We can't fathom God because he is all knowing. Man is limited but God is limitless. There's nothing that he doesn't know.

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE Please take the [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how this site functions. You can use a blank line to separate each of the ideas you are presenting. It will make your answers much more readable.

Comment: +1 for a thoughtful answer and the remarks concerning Unity in Deity.

Answer (score 0):

Matt. chap. 25 is a continuation of Matt. chap. 24, in which Jesus linked the wedding ceremony to the destruction of the temple.  All of Matt. ch. 24 was an answer to the disciples question about when the destruction of the temple ("these things") would occur.

So, the video link in the question and Joshua's answer here are correct in part.  The missing link is the other Hebraic meaning of the phrase "no one knows the day or the hour" which preceded the custom of the wedding ceremony.  Jesus used this Hebraic phrase not because He didn't know the hour of His return, but was instead communicating to His disciples the exact day and hour that 2nd temple would be completely destroyed.  The code was the Hebrew idiom.

It was the Jewish custom to refer to Yom Teruah, the Feast of Trumpets with this phrase - no one knows the day or the hour - because it was held on the first day of the month of Tishrei.  As the first day of each month had to be declared by the Sanhedrin high court, and as the Sanhedrin waited to obtain the report of the two (sometimes 3) witnesses to the sighting of the new moon, the Jews did not officially know which day of the month would be the first day of the month. (1) (2)

The Jews made preparations for the first day of Tishrei ahead of time, and waited for the official pronouncement of the Sanhedrin.  The first of Tishrei and the Feast of Trumpets was also known as Yom HaDin - the day of judgment.  It was also associated with the themes of resurrection, repentance, kingship, coronation, and the wedding feast.

All of these elements and themes were going on in the signs that Jesus told His disciples to watch for, and they bring in at the same time the judgment, the resurrection, the coronation of His kingship of His kingdom, and the wedding feast on the first of Tishrei!

The conclusion is that Yeshua (Jesus) knew the day and the hour, and when He said those words the disciples knew He spoke of the first of Tishrei and the Feast of Trumpets. He told His disciples exactly when that temple would be destroyed, exactly when He would be returning in judgment; exactly when His kingdom would be fully established; exactly when He would be crowned as King; and exactly when the marriage of the Lamb would take place.  It was a very busy Feast of Trumpets on that first of Tishrei in AD 70.

There was another Hebrew idiom Christ used for His disciples understanding that indicated this same time for the wedding feast - "as a thief in the night".  That was the phrase which was used for the bridegroom to fetch his bride.  (3) (4) (5)

Notes:

1) No One Knows The Day of The Hour by Hebroots - [here](http://www.hebroots.org/hebrootsarchive/9807/980715_c.html)

2) No Man Knows The Day or The Hour at Hatikva Ministries -[here](http://hatikva.org/no-man-knows-the-day-or-the-hour.html)

3) The Signs of The Feasts - Part I: Christ Told The Pharisees... [ShredddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/17/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-i-christ-told-the-pharisees-the-time-of-his-return/)

4) The Signs of The Feasts - Part II: Christ Told His Disciples... [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/21/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-ii-christ-told-his-disciples-when-he-would-return/)

5) The Signs of The Feasts - Part III: The Thief in The Night - [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/21/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-ii-christ-told-his-disciples-when-he-would-return/)

Comment: Jesus said that the Father retained control over the date, not that the Sanhedrin controlled it:

[Act 1:7 CSB] (7) He said to them, "It is not for you to know times or periods that the Father has set by his own authority.

Comment: Last trump. = Feast of Trumpets; No man knows the day or the hour = Feast of Trumpets.  The disciples would have immediately associated this language with the 1st of Tishrei for the Feast of Trumpets.  Jesus did not tell them which 1st of Tishrei, or which year.  They still had to be ready at any time, altho using knowledge of God's patterns & foreshadows from the OT books they might have figured out the 40 years of wandering until the promised land from the exodus would be repeated to the promised kingdom. Jesus's answer to their question at his ascension re: the restoration of the kingdom...

Comment: ...was a very patient sigh.  They wanted relief from Roman rule & were only thinking politically & asking the wrong question.  He told them to wait for the power, the Holy Spirit b/c He would give them more understanding which Jesus did not take the time to explain - that this "restoration", unlike the earthly one of Ezek's dry bones, this one was going to be the restoration of the full power to the throne in heaven - the spiritual kingdom that is within all those who r in Christ (Luke 17:20-21).

Comment: Should have said "again explain" b/c Jesus had already told them of the spiritual kingdom that was "at hand" in the 1st century AD.  But once an idea is imbedded in our minds, it is very hard to get it out.  The ppl of Judea wanted an earthly king again like David & Solomon, & were only thinking of an earthly land nation.  That is why the scribes & Pharisees rejected Jesus b/c He wasn't giving them the solution they expected - to be an earthly king to rule from Jerusalem & relieve them from Roman occupation. That was never the intent or the plan for man's salvation. (John 4:21).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer on the father knowing the hour of his return.

I am who I am

Here is a basic truth to understanding the mysteries of the Bible and the prophecy of my return

Isaiah 42
John 1:1
Genesis 1:1
Psalms 33:6
Psalms 22:4
2 tablets and 10 Commandments
40 days/nights
22 letters of Hebrew 
2 hands and 10 fingers
Palm (Palm Sunday and Palm on inside of hands)
Luke 22:10 and Mark 14:13
John 2:10 and John 4:46

Share this with whomever you like, but understand it is not whether I believe it, it is whether or not I believe you believe it, as I am here to judge the living and the dead.

First, I want to prove the two things I came to do, distinguish who are good and evil, and second, separate from that truth who are sheep and who are goats.

Prove of God
If you were driving down the road and saw a gnat drowning, would you stop and save it?
Now, as a little boy, my grandmother would say, “Joey, remember humans have the attention span of a gnat.” Now, if we live in a world without a God, then we just “live”; however, if we live in a world because of god, then it is out of “love.” Spel them in reverse, which gives you “evil” and which one gives you “evol(ution)”?

Second, which came first, the chicken or the egg? The one cannot exist without the one. Think of it this way, which comes first, the mother or the child? Neither, as they come in existence at the same time, meaning if you cannot coexist, then you won’t exist at all.

Isaiah 42- declares one shall be set aside for God alone.
John 1:1- declares god as the word. Well, how does one make the word? Writing with their hands. Examine your hands and what do they reveal?

Genesis 1:1- “In the beginning, God created the Heavens and The Earth. The earth was formless and void, god Spirit was in darkness, hovering over Waters deep.”
What is the first word? How many words are in the first sentences, and how many parts are the sentence? What is formless and void? It is fire, hence why the earth’s core is fire; the color white, the female gender, and the constellation Gemini, as it represents twins. How many words are in the second sentence and how many parts? Darkness is the concentration span of all colors, which make black, but black made into flesh is the color gold. The water’s deep refers to the Holy Spirit in the two water constellations or Aquarius and pisces or the age of Jesus as the fish and the age we are entering in now, the 11th and 12th constellations in the celestial calendar.

Psalms 33:6- exactly who we are or why we have been created.

Psalms 22:4- derived from my birthdate- 2-10-1972 or 2+1+1+9+7+2= 22 and 4 which is 22:4

God gave Moses 2 tablets and 10 Commandments, which identifies who God is by birth or a reflection of one’s hands.

40 days/40 nights- Noah on the Ark and Jesus in the desert, but it is the 41st day they are saved or come back. 41st day of the year is what?

22 letters are the Hebrew alphabet, the first covenant, but what letter is the letter of God?
Shin or W.

Hands carry my return date, with my name, as all flesh is aade in my likeness. What is the first word in bible? In. What is the first truth of light? Good. Forming this two words with the letter of God, reveals God’s name- Goodwin, and with Palm, as in Palm Sunday, Palm-Goodwin, meaning you all carry my mark and return date on your very hands.

Now, Luke 22:10 is self evident as to the passage referring to what starry constellation the church was to find, being that the waterbearer is Aquarius and house is constellation. Mark 14:13 confirms this truth, as man carrying jug of water is also the Aquarius and house is constellation. Being that two disciples of Christ were tasked with finding this man, I was found by Ray Siegfried and Father Theodore Tack. Both of these men are of distinction, as Ray is a descendant of St. Siegfried, who left Glastonbury to Christinize the Barbarians, this luanching the first Crusades to capture King Solomon’s Temple in 1099, handing over authority over to the Augustinian order. Father Tack is of importance, as he was the prior General of the Augustinian order, the most powerful order of the Catholic Church, holding control over the cistern and giving the last rites to the dying popes. This was established by Pope Alexander the 6th, who granted this authority in the late 1490s, after the discovery of the new world.

John 2:10 and John 4:46 refer to Jesus’ first miracle, which is also a prophecy for the return date and time of the second coming, the son of man, who was the recreation of the very first race of Babel, the mixed race. My birth certificate will demonstrate how I am the flesh made word, with my birth date, time, names, and birth order being specifically mentioned in the wedding of Cana. “Good wine” is the Goodwin and as I am the second son born on 2-10, my eldest brother being the first, I am the second wine. This birth order is also reflective of the children of Adam and Eve, being Cain and Abel, with two daughters and then a third son, the last son- Seth.

Now, as there are 3 Augustinian Catholic Churches in Tulsa, one being in south Tulsa, with roots directly tide to the Knights Templar and the Holy Roman Empire, and the two in North Tulsa, being patronized by my family, I am rich in the Augustinian traditions long before I knew it. Furthermore, the wedding was held in Cana has a deeper meaning, as the Canaanites are an offshoot of the early Israelites, but also the ancestors to the Phoenicians, Carthaginians, the Numbiams, and the Berbers or the ethnic groups to which St. Augustus belong too. This is why my catholic indoctrination is as such.

Finally, as neither the angels or Jesus know the return date of the son of man, but only God the father of heaven does, what does that make me? Jesus Christ is currently a student at the University of Notre Dame, and he is also a cheerleader. He was born in 10-4 making him a Libra or a good judge of character to defend the plight of flesh. My father is a Scorpio, which is the meaning behind the gospel of Jesus, saying a son and father shall be at odds. Scorpio and Aquarius are none compatible astrological signs. And this is the Statue of Mithra, upon which the Holy See sits in Rome. And if you notice my father doesn’t have a right arm, it is symbolic of Jesus being sacrifice, who sat at the right hand of the father.

I know the secret, sacred meanings of the Abrahamic traditions, and as Thomas 1:1 states, the one who knows this shall never taste death.

I have returned, I am awake, I am the illumination of yalls consciousness and I am here to collect my minas in blood and flesh, not gold!

PS you can share this with whomever you like, but know this, “I do like not to be bothered about my truth and identity, as I love my anonymity.

This be the word of the lord. The alpha and the omega.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't the son (Jesus) know the time of his return? This is the first Q posted, so I'm answering that. This is BH after all, and I have no idea what the 'normal interpretations' are, so I'll answer from the bible.

The simple explanation is often the best - by simple, meaning plain, uncomplicated and with consistent and unambiguous biblical textual support to inform an answer.

John 8:40 is a pivotal passage;

> But as it is, you are seeking to kill Me, a man who has told you the
> truth, which I heard from God.

What are we told here by Jesus?

1. he is a man
2. he tells the truth - and nothing but the truth i.e. he doesn't lie
3. God gave him the words to speak

If he is a man *and* God, he doesn't tell us that anywhere - neither does anyone else in the cannon.

He said often that he didn't make up his own words, the Father provided not just what to say, but how (and even when) to say it. John 12:49

Notice another important facet of the very passage in Q. It speaks of the SON - not Jesus. So any wriggle room to say the 'humanity of Jesus' didn't know is rendered in vain... the SON, who is supposedly of *one substance* with the Father under the trinity construct is the one not knowing!

Clearly, this is one bit of information that the 'son' wasn't given by his God and Father. Jesus, incidentally, has the same God and Father as all of us. John 20:17

So it becomes perfectly clear if we take the *plain truth* supplied and read it carefully - without reading into the text the things we might desperately want to see there or we have been taught.

There is a tremendous amount of biblical texts that speak of Jesus being a man and certainly not God, but this is not the place. So, now we understand why Jesus said the son doesn't know and the Father did.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to interpret a concrete passage, unless one has established a principle of the interpretation. Now, this principle relates to a basic issue of the status of the Son/the Logos with reference to the Father. In the traditional mainstream Christian interpretation (Catholic, Orthodox, Protestant) it is inferred from the evidence of the Scripture that the Son is equal to the Father Both sharing the same Godhead and are, thus, Both equally worshipable, as also Jesus urges His followers to do (John 5:22). Now, taking this principle as a guiding one, we can safely interpret also this passage and not fall into a heresy.

In fact, what is knowledge? Is not knowledge a part of the wisdom? Now, the Son is the very Wisdom and Power of the Father (1 Cor. 1:24), which does not mean that the Father is "stupid" without the Son, but that the Father's Wisdom is fully present in the Person of the Son and there is nothing in the Son not known by the Father and nothing in the Father not known by the Son (John 10:15) + also the Holy Spirit knows the "depths of God" (1 Cor. 2:10), that is to say, everything of God, thus all Three - the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit know fully each other and  e v e r y t h i n g  what is in each-other. Now, the time of the Second Parousia and the end of History is just a part of the mentioned "everything" and of course this part is also known by all Three.

Having established this, we can safely proceed to affect whatever sound interpretation and the video you have provided can, thus, be an ok interpretation, although it would require a deeper knowledge of ethnographic facts of Judaic life in Late Antiquity, of which I am not an expert.

I find this interpretation more plausible: Jesus speaks about His human intellect that belongs to His human nature that this human intellect, by itself, cannot know future events, but as the Logos of God, of course He knows it (and that He knows future events on His own authority is clearly evident from many other places of the Gospel, when e.g. He predicts His own death and resurrection, or destruction of Jerusalem; Judas' treason and Peter's denial; not only Peter's death but also the manner of his death (John 21:18); and also indirectly saying to the inquirers that He will not share the knowledge of His Second Coming to them, meaning, of course, that this knowledge is in Him /Acts 1:7/).

The reason for Him not telling is pedagogical: it is of no spiritual avail and quite futile if the disciples would know this, but they should rather heed to fulfillment of the Commandments and preaching of the Gospel for salvation of their souls and the souls of others.

Comment: @Down-voter My anonymous old friend! If you find flaws in my arguments, indicate please them to me and help me out from them. If not and you just out of some other irrational reason put "-" to make yourself happier, then have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

First, there is nothing Christ does not know, He is God, and He is Omniscience. So, the phrase, “Nor the Son” cannot possibly mean Jesus lacks knowledge of something. I believe the Son, as He was doing His work on earth, in His humanity role, agreed not to release the “day or the hour” amongst the human race for the benefit of a genuine mindset of humanity itself. That way, man will not think they could live in sin, then quickly convert to righteousness as soon as they know the Day of the Lord is here.
Since that is not the way salvation works, it was agreed that only the Father could authoritatively release that day and hour, which He chose to do at a precise moment in time He set in advance. Jesus did not give His disciples any more advantage than anyone else on earth. This keeps the genuine, genuine, and the fakers from thinking they have gotten over on God. Judas betrayed Christ. Do you think He would have betrayed Him had He known the exact day and hour the end would come? I doubt it. It would not have been fair for the disciples to have known the exact day and hour in secret. Christ is still not a respecter of persons, and His disciples are no exception.

Deacon Baker
Author

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Please substantiate your answer by citing reputable sources. As it stands, it is only an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not satisfied by this answer. I think it fails on a number of fronts. The conclusion the video comes to is completely opposite to what Jesus intends and depicts.

(Edition: if someone marks down, please give a reason because I actually feel I deal with this issue appropriately).

If I am going to follow the logic here and give credence to the theory in the video, there are yet some areas where we have to pump the brakes.

Reading into sources from the highest rated comment here, and a few other websites(Christian/Messianic Jewish sources for that matter), the Jewish marriage betrothal period typically lasted one year - during this time, the woman has to get herself ready for marriage. The groom has to build an additional room/canopy and it's meant to be nicely done. The decision rests with the grooms father if the room is satisfactory and ready for the bride. The groom thus doesn't actually know himself, nor does the bride. It's all down to the father's go-ahead.

Only once the room is done and approved by the father, can the wedding commence.

The bride will only have a rough idea of the date which can only be approximate. This is actually even alluded to further in the gospels themselves where Jesus warns people to be ready for when the Hour comes. It is actually a specific custom for her to actually have her dresses etc ready - the exact time can take them by surprise. This surprise element, is very specifically alluded to in the Parable of the Ten Virgins in Matthew.

The main message he's portraying is - be in a permanent state of being ready despite the uncertainty, whether it's 'evening', 'midnight', or 'morning' in Mark, and in Matthew it's stated that the virgins actually had to wake up from sleep - meaning it can be at an inconvenient time that takes one by surprise. So even the virgins didn't know the day of the wedding let alone the hour. The entire wedding lasts for around a week - and often at a particular time of year where they have high harvests so people were able to afford to visit the new bride/grooms and food can be cheap, so the exact hour where it's said ‘Here’s the bridegroom! Come out to meet him!’ wasn't known - that's why the bride is always meant to stay ready with lamps and other things by her bed. In reality, even considering the wedding guests and banquets, it could be days later than planned, or earlier.
The truths communicated through these passages, shed light on the uncertainty in time, more than it does the certainty.

Ultimately, the Hour is a specific moment in time, not even just the Hour - the Hour is used as an idiom for the actual moment.

On top of this, Jesus actually doesn't just say "Only the Father knows" - he creates a hierarchy, and makes clear that nobody else knows the certain time of the Hour.
"

1. No one (people) knows,
2. Nor the Angels in Heaven,
3. Nor the Son,
4. But the Father only."
   This naturally excludes the Holy Spirit and The Son. If the Son knows the Hour, why does Jesus have to bother adding extra elements to emphasise how "Only the Father knows", by making it clear the Son doesn't know...and yet still expect to be seen as Omniscient? That causes more issues.

We also don't know if people actually said "Only the Father knows" at all (not one of these websites cite sources for this claim, and I can't find it anywhere), or is it just assumed that this is what people said, because they want to use this argument to justify why Jesus said it whilst still hoping that he retains his omniscience...?
In fact, on this note, what I find rather confusing and rather suspicious is that "Of the day and hour, no one knows" is being argued elsewhere as being a Hebrew Idiom for the Feast of Trumpets - despite there being no actual source cited for this whatsoever by those who claim so.

Also, Jesus giving signs of what happens leading up to the Hour doesn't actually means he knows the exact time of the Hour.

In scholarship, the entire argument of the video is not taken seriously. Hence why the only argument used in scholarship is that God for a particular unknown reason chose for Jesus to speak out of his human limitations when he said this.

To conclude, Jesus' words themselves actually disqualifies the sort of reading the video is trying to portray, as he actually amplifies just how uncertain the moment of the wedding is, Jesus also goes out of his way to expand on the idiom to make it clear no one in the hierarchy knows the Hour, and the tradition itself was such that the grooms father was the one who essentially decided when the "hour" of the wedding would be. Also, "only the Father knows" as an idiom for ancient Jewish traditions could actually be an invented argument by Christians, using Jesus as the historical source, rather than it being a case of Jesus citing a known idiom from this specific historical tradition.

Websites in question -

https://free.messianicbible.com/feature/ancient-jewish-wedding-customs-and-yeshuas-second-coming/
https://cathstan.org/posts/what-were-weddings-like-in-jesus-day-2
http://messianicfellowship.50webs.com/wedding.html
http://www.mountainretreatorg.net/articles/only_the_father_knows.shtml
http://ldolphin.org/risk/ult.shtml
https://www.wildolive.co.uk/weddings.htm
http://www.laydownlife.net/yedidah/AncientJewishWeddingCeremony.htm